# MIssing EfTextTemplateHost

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

Applying Reverse Engineer Code first, appears this bug:

> Compiling transformation: No se puede encontrar el tipo o el nombre de espacio de nombres 'EfTextTemplateHost' (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 1):

EfTextTemplateHost is part of the [EF Powertools](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1756). So make sure it is installed correctly.

Add this to to the T4 file and change the placehoders [] to match your system:

```
<#@ assembly name="C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[vsVersion]\Extensions\[extensionHash]\EFPowerTools.dll" #>
```