# Customize reverse Engineer Templates with EFPowerTools for VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ef-code-first

I am working on customizing Code First Model with VS2013 Update 5. It created for me nice templates
    Context.tt
    Entity.tt
    Mapping.tt

for some reason the property for the templates were missing the CustomTool name so I had to provide it with TextTemplatingFileGenerator
When I run it returned me an error
    The type or namespace name 'EfTextTemplateHost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

based on the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658612/missing-eftexttemplatehost#)
I added following lines into my template

```
<#@ assembly name="C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\djbjxbcm.12d\EFPowerTools.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Utilities" #>
```

now I am getting

```
Running transformation: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Utilities.EfTextTemplateHost'.
```

Any ideas how to deal with it?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a mater of fact the Custom Reverse Engineer Code First templates are not designed to run as a separate scripts. As it mentioned in the context menu below, 
[image: Context Menu]
they are just customization for the "Reverse Engineer Code First" Process and will be initiated at the "Reverse Engineer Code First"context item clicked. 
No tt file properties should be changed.
To make the templates work perfectly well just follow the example [here](https://romiller.com/2012/05/09/customizing-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-the-ef-power-tools/)

as it mention in the article, it is safe to ignore that EfTextTemplateHost related error.